# Polymorphic (entity framework) query through expressions

Tags: entity-framework, polymorphism, expression

I have a entity class strucure like:

```
public class Base
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
}

public class Instance : Base 
{
    public int Prop1 { get; set; }
}
```

I can query this normally like (on IQueryable< Base >):

```
.Where(p => (p as Instance).Prop1 == 1)
```

This works great.... but i need this in a flexible Expression so i tried:

```
var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Base));
var property = typeof(Instance).GetProperty("Prop1");
var constant = Expression.Constant(1);

//NOT WORKING LIKE THIS
var convertedParam = Expression.Convert(param, typeof(Instance));

var memberAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(convertedParam, property);
var equals = Expression.Equal(memberAccess, constant);
```

This results in a nice error : Unable to cast the type 'Base' to type 'Instance'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types. So i need an Expression version of (p as Instance)

What should i do (I need to use expressions...)?

Comment: Expression.TypeAs...... DOH!

Comment: `.Where(p => ((Instance)p).Prop1 == 1)` also works, so when using Expression, it's an equivalent of `Expression.Convert`. But it's strange that `Expression.Convert` does not work as what you said. So if you mean `Expression.TypeAs` is the answer, you should add a simple answer with some code and mark it for others referencing in future. This is an interesting issue I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by using Expression.TypeAs. TypeAs is the same as (p as Instance).

```
var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Base));
var property = typeof(Instance).GetProperty("Prop1");
var constant = Expression.Constant(1);

//WORKING LIKE THIS :)
var convertedParam = Expression.TypeAs(param, typeof(Instance));

var memberAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(convertedParam, property);
var equals = Expression.Equal(memberAccess, constant);
```